# Why is this pipe not working inside a for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, pipeline

When I run the code, it outputs `FIND: Parameter format not correct` and `The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.`. From this, I'm pretty sure the for loop can't handle the pipe and/or redirection. I'm not sure what to do from here, I've tried running it outside a loop, and that works fine, but inside the loop it chucks the dummy. Does anyone know why, or how I can fix this?

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (set_1.txt) do (
    type set_2.txt | find %%a > nul
    if !errorlevel! EQU 1 (
        echo %%a
    )
) 

endlocal
pause
```

And before anyone says it, I'm aware this is not the most efficient method for finding strings in files, but it doesn't matter for the file sizes I'm dealing with.

Comment: You should try it at the command prompt first `type someFile | find word` simply fails, as `find` requires a `"word"` in quotes

Comment: Why using a pipe here? why not simply stating the file name as an argument of `find`, like `find "%%a" "set_2.txt"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type someFile | find word` simply fails, as find requires a "word" in quotes.

So the solution is to change your line to

```
type set_2.txt | find "%%a" > nul
if !errorlevel! EQU 0 (
     ....
```

Or even simpler

```
type set_2.txt | find "%%a" > nul || echo %%a not found
```

Comment: Actually, for the purposes of this script, it should be `||`. I'm looking for strings in set_1 that aren't in set_2 and echoing them. Hence, I only want to echo `%%a` if `find "%%a"` fails. For more info see [SS64](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: @IamaTerribleProgrammer, since you used `if !errorlevel! EQU 0` in the code of your question, `&&` is the appropriate alternative...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I've amended the question to reflect my intentions.